# ssh - Control socket does not exist - Operation timed out

Tags: ssh

When I try to SSH on to my remote desktop from my Mac, I get this error message:

```
$ ssh -vvvv john@dev-dsk-john.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/john/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/john/.ssh/config line 26: Applying options for *
debug1: /Users/john/.ssh/config line 40: Applying options for dev-dsk*.amazon.com
debug1: /Users/john/.ssh/config line 165: Applying options for *.us-east-*.amazon.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
debug1: Control socket "/tmp/ssh_mux_dev-dsk-john.com_22_john" does not exist
debug2: resolving "dev-dsk-john.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to dev-dsk-john.com [10.1.133.160] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.1.1.1 port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host dev-dsk-john.com port 22: Operation timed out
```

The connection hangs at
`debug1: Connecting to dev-dsk-john.com [10.1.133.160] port 22.`

It was working three days ago.

The system says the host is still active, so I'm pretty sure the computer is still powered on.

Comment: Don't vote to close this without giving a reason why. Somebody might run into the same problem and search "Control socket does not exist - Operation timed out" and need this post.

Comment: Stackoverflow is for questions about software development. ssh is a general purpose utility. It's not specifically a developer tool, and every possible question someone could have about it isn't automatically on topic here. Further, "Operation timed out" isn't a programming error or an ssh-specific failure mode; it's a generic problem which any TCP/IP-based utility might encounter. And "Control socket does not exist" isn't an error message (unless there's a particular reason why you _should_ have a control socket) and it's not related to the timeout.

Comment: Well then where does this belong (and why is there an ssh tag in stack overflow in the first place)?

Comment: I usually recommend [su] or [unix.se], assuming you're doing this on a unix system. You should clarify whether you're asking about the operation timed out message or the control socket message, because they're not related to each other.

Comment: @MichaelLafayette Look at the tag description: "[SSH] is a cryptographic network protocol [...] Use this tag for programming questions related to [SSH]"

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem today, and finally managed to fixed it.

I first verified that the control socket really doesn't exist. My path was "/home/ethan/.ssh/controlmasters/ethan@a.b.c.d:22" and this didn't exist.

I then ran ssh like:

```
ssh -M -S /home/ethan/.ssh/controlmasters/ethan@<ipaddr>:22  server.example.org
```

Now, it connects and also creates the control socket. Subsequently, I could open another ssh and that didn't require password and things worked normally.