# Unable to connect to Ansible via SSH

Tags: ssh, ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I create a host file with the below content

```
[web]
167.172.xxx.xxx
```

I have a user `root` and `dojo360` on the web server and the public key has also been added to `authorized_keys` file.

When I run the command  `ansible web -m ping -i hosts` I get the below error

```
167.172.xxx.xxx | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: ssh: connect to host 167.172.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I have tried other variations of the hosts file, below is another one I have tried that also doesn't work

```
[web]
167.172.xxx.xxx ansible_connection=ssh ansible_user=user ansible_ssh_private_key_file=~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

However, I can ssh into the server using `ssh dojo360@167.172.xxx.xxx` with no problem, I am new to Ansible, but this shouldn't take over 24 hours, please help, I am stuck.

Running with `-vvv` I get

```
ansible 2.9.6
  config file = None
  configured module search path = ['/Users/g.james/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /Users/g.james/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ansible
  executable location = /Users/g.james/Library/Python/3.7/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.7.6 (default, Dec 30 2019, 19:38:26) [Clang 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.16)]
No config file found; using defaults
setting up inventory plugins
host_list declined parsing /Users/g.james/dojo360/d3-scripts/server/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
script declined parsing /Users/g.james/dojo360/d3-scripts/server/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
auto declined parsing /Users/g.james/dojo360/d3-scripts/server/hosts as it did not pass its verify_file() method
Parsed /Users/g.james/dojo360/d3-scripts/server/hosts inventory source with ini plugin
Loading callback plugin minimal of type stdout, v2.0 from /Users/g.james/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/ansible/plugins/callback/minimal.py
META: ran handlers
<67.172.xxx.xxx> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root
<67.172.xxx.xxx> SSH: EXEC ssh -vvv -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/g.james/.ssh/id_rsa.pub"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o 'User="root"' -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/g.james/.ansible/cp/5d3d6b8351 67.172.xxx.xxx '/bin/sh -c '"'"'echo ~root && sleep 0'"'"''
<67.172.xxx.xxx> (255, b'', b'OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 67.172.xxx.xxx is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket "/Users/g.james/.ansible/cp/5d3d6b8351" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 67.172.xxx.xxx [67.172.xxx.xxx] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 67.172.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out\r\nssh: connect to host 67.172.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out\r\n')
67.172.xxx.xxx | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh: OpenSSH_7.9p1, LibreSSL 2.7.3\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 48: Applying options for *\r\ndebug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname 67.172.xxx.xxx is address\r\ndebug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master\r\ndebug1: Control socket \"/Users/g.james/.ansible/cp/5d3d6b8351\" does not exist\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct\r\ndebug1: Connecting to 67.172.xxx.xxx [67.172.xxx.xxx] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: connect to address 67.172.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out\r\nssh: connect to host 67.172.xxx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

Comment: re-run the command with -vvvv `ansible web -m ping -i hosts -vvvv`. Also it says operation timed out this means the connection to the target server is not present. Can you try telnet using ansible ??

Comment: @error404, I tried it with the flag -vvv and it says `Control socket does not exist`, I don't know what that means, I have also updated the question with the full text. Please take a look

Comment: `ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: root` this should be some other user like `dojo360` OR you are trying to connect to target server using `root` as a user ? For control https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43595294/ssh-control-socket-does-not-exist-operation-timed-out

Comment: @error404 I am trying to connect using root, I also tried for the other user, none works

Comment: ` /Users/g.james/.ansible/cp/5d3d6b8351\ ` seems like some directory permissions issue. Can you check this path for permissions refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42011478/remote-tmp-directory-not-set-for-ansible-script-execution

Comment: @error404 permissions seesm fine

Answer (score 1):

It looks more of the network problem over ssh authentication issue. Is there a proxy that you are using in your network to connect to this servers?
If yes you need to pass proxy details in your command.

Comment: I have done all of that, different computers, different network, I always get the same result

Comment: Also, If that were the case I wouldn't be able to do normal ssh to the same server

Comment: As the error says `unreachable` so network was suspected. You can have proxy settings at user level. Anyways you can you test your command as `ansible web -m ping -i hosts -e ansible_ssh_user=dojo360`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using root with ansible and dojo360 with your ssh test.